# How to hide checkbox name in receipt when not checked?

Tags: c#, checkbox

I would like to know how I can hide the check box name in the receipt when it is no checked the following is my code:

```
richTextBox2.Visible = true;
tabControl1.Visible = false;
richTextBox2.Text = FirstName.Text + ' ' + Surname.Text +   (System.Environment.NewLine) +
FullAddress.Text + (System.Environment.NewLine) +
ContactNumber.Text + (System.Environment.NewLine) +
EmailAddress.Text + (System.Environment.NewLine) +
dob.Text +
(System.Environment.NewLine) +
"----------------------------------------------------------" +
(System.Environment.NewLine) +
textBox1.Text + (System.Environment.NewLine) +
textBox2.Text + (System.Environment.NewLine) +
textBox3.Text + (System.Environment.NewLine) +
"You have chosen to have a banner with the following text:" +
(System.Environment.NewLine) +
BannerText.Text + (System.Environment.NewLine) +
"at the price of " + label43.Text + (System.Environment.NewLine) +
"You have asked for the following accessories: " +
(System.Environment.NewLine) + MasksCB.Text+
(System.Environment.NewLine) + PartyCB.Text+
(System.Environment.NewLine) + CrackersCB.Text +
(System.Environment.NewLine) + HatsCB.Text+
(System.Environment.NewLine) + label18.Text;
```

HatsCB PartyCB CrackersCB and MasksCB are all the check boxes. When the receipt is printed they are visible even when the boxes have not been checked. I would like to know how to hide them when the boxes aren't checked and make them visible when the boxes are checked in the receipt.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **[?: operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)** like this:

```
 "You have asked for the following accessories: " +
 (MasksCB.Checked  ? System.Environment.NewLine + MasksCB.Text : "") + 
 (PartyCB.Checked  ? System.Environment.NewLine + PartyCB.Text : "") + 
 ...
```

Which will only print the text if the Checkbox is checked